# Getting table row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The following query can be used to find the total row count for a specific table in a database

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [TotalRowCount] FROM table_name;
```

It is also possible to get the row count for all tables by joining back to the table's partition based off the tables' HEAP (index_id = 0) or cluster clustered index (index_id = 1) using the following script:

```
SELECT [Tables].name AS [TableName],
SUM( [Partitions].[rows] ) AS [TotalRowCount] 
FROM sys.tables AS [Tables] 
JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions] 
   ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id] 
   AND [Partitions].index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
 --WHERE [Tables].name = N'table name' we uncomment for a specific table
GROUP BY [Tables].name;
```

If someone can please explain this code, if we can get the count by simply using count() , why do we use the second code?

Comment: The latter gets the count for every table by using the stored statistics not the roes, and is not for a specific table; they don't really appear to be related. What are you actually asking here?

Comment: @Larnu That is the point where i'm confused too, it is given as a  row_count example in a book,  the sentence between the codes **It is also possible to get the row count for all tables by joining back to the table's partition based off the tables' HEAP (index_id = 0) or cluster clustered index (index_id = 1) using the following script: ** says it is also possible by the given query, I don't understand this example query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the second code because you can parameterize the table name, so you can get the counts for multiple tables at the same time.

In the first code, you would have to use dynamic SQL.

In addition, the second code is much faster, because it doesn't actually read any data from the table.  I do think there are some circumstances where the results may not be exactly the same due to locking on the table.  That is usually not important because it only affects a handful of rows.

Comment: Right sir, Thank you